# Why is AsyncTask Blocking UI Thread?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Why does my AsyncTask block the UI Thread?

My application becomes unresponsive while the AsyncTask is taking place.

This is called in the UI Thread:

```
new AsyncFetch().execute();
```

This is my AsyncTask class:

```
class AsyncFetch extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... args) {
        String data = null;
        try {
            data = DataHandler.httpFetch(DataHandler.API_URL);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return data;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String data) {
        DataHandler.AsyncFetchResult(data);
    }

}
```

Comment: may be this will be the problem.DataHandler.AsyncFetchResult(data);...show its code

Comment: Hmm you're right. Let me do some tests on that. That method saves the data to cache and parses it.

Comment: What is it contains DataHandler.AsyncFetchResult method?

Comment: remember..onPostExecute runs on ui thread. thats why it block yours ui.

Comment: Don't you do the following call instead 'new AsyncFetch().execute().get();' which is blocking. Beware of '.get()'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`onPostExecute` runs on the UI thread. Avoid doing too much work here. Do the heavy stuff in `doInBackground` and then just update the UI (or whatever you need to do) in `onPostExecute`.